# Android camera "View details"

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, camera

Few days ago, I was taking a picture of a machine and the camera app showed a tooltip saying **View details** I tapped on it and a new screen appeared saying *Product* in the title and a list of numbers in it.

I have not managed to get that screen/tooltip again, but I am curious to know what it was, any idea? It is on a Honor 5C with Android 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Honor 5C Camera App used for scanning the QR code and obtain the contacts !!](https://club.hihonor.com/in/tips.267/honor-5c-camera-app-used-for-scanning-the-qr-code-and-obtain-the-contacts-.5585?flag=r) explains this as a smart way to add contacts without typing

> - Go to contacts
> - Click on the QR code of the contact
> - The QR code will be appearing on the screen
> - Open the Camera App in the Honor 5C phone
> - Click on the **View details**. Click on Create new contact and Click on Add to contacts

I don't have that device but this seems to be what you saw and introduced in EMUI 4.1

Comment: It is not exactly the QR code of a contact (or a QR code at all), but I presume the app might have identified something on the machine and applied the same principle.